# What makes a differential equation, linear or non-linear?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

Among these differential equations why one is linear while other is non-linear?
[image]

What is criteria to find out whether a differential equation is linear or non-linear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A differential equation is linear if there are no products of $y$ and its differentials.

For example, $y\cdot \frac{dy}{dx}=e^x$ would be non-linear, as well as $y^2+\frac{dy}{dx}=e^x$.

Comment: why is the second diff eqn non linear ?

Comment: @gansub It is not even a differential equation, so I edited it, but since $y^2=y \cdot y$, there are products of the unknown function and it differentials (which can be the unknown function itself).

Answer (score 1):

Linear differential equations: They do not contain any powers of the unknown function or its derivatives (apart from 1). Your first equation falls under this. If this equation had something like $\frac{dy}{dx}^n$, $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}^n$ where $n \neq 0 \ \text{or}\ 1$, this would make it non-linear.

Non-linear: may contain any powers of the unknown function or its derivatives (where power $> 0$) or even a product of unknown function and its derivatives.
Your second equation is non-linear because it contains a power of the unknown function (in this case, $y(x)^2$)

The distinction is important because linear differential equations are generally easier to solve than non-linear equations.