# Non-Linearity of a First Order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was working on the classification of ODEs as linear and non linear. For the equation $\ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y(2-3x)}{x(1-3y)}$ I understand that it is a first order ODE where y is the independent variable and x is the dependent variable. I don't completely understand though why it is considered a non-linear ODE.Is it because  $\ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y(2-3x)}{x(1-3y)}$ =  $\ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2y}{x(1-3y)}-\frac{3y}{1-3y}$, but I am not sure how this determines the linearity.

Comment: Assuming $1-3y \neq 0$, multiply both sides with $x(1-3y)$ and distribute the brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give a formal answer. Define the operator $L$ by
$$ Ly = \dfrac{y(2-3x)}{x(1-3y)}$$
Then, for $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ we have
$$L(\lambda y) = \dfrac{(\lambda y)(2-3x)}{x(1-3(\lambda y))} \neq \lambda \cdot\dfrac{y(2-3x)}{x(1-3y)}= \lambda (Ly)$$
Hence $L$ is not a linear operator, from which we conclude that the ODE $y'= Ly$ is non-linear.

Answer (score 1):

It's nonlinear because of the $1-3y$ in the denominator.  In order to be linear, the right side would have to be expressible in the form $a(x) + b(x) y$.  It isn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you re-arrange your equation, it will contain a product of the unknown variable $(y)$ and its derivative $\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$-that's one criterion for non-linearity.
See this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1374248/what-makes-a-differential-equation-linear-or-non-linear/1374252#1374252) for more.

$$x(1-3y)\frac{dy}{dx} = y(2-3x) \implies x \frac{dy}{dx}-3y\frac{dy}{dx} = y(2-3x)$$

If you divide through by $y$, then the equation will contain a power of $y$ which is not equal to 1 (Another condition that makes it non-linear).